# Using socket.ui to emit a message to specific rooms does not do anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

In my react app, I set up a connection to a specific room based on a roomId parameter:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const roomId = window.location.search.replace('?roomId=', '');
    this.setState({ roomId });
    this.socket = io();
    if (!this.socket.socket) {
        this.socket.connect();
    }

    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log(this.state.roomId);

        this.socket.emit('room', this.state.roomId);
    });

    this.socket.on('message', this.handleMessage)
}
```

Now on my server.js I join and listen for messages like this:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('room', function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });
    socket.on('message', function(data) {
        socket.to(data.roomId).emit(data);
    });
});
```

But when I send a message, the other browser window connected to the same roomId does not receive any messages:

```
const message = {
    roomId: this.state.roomId,
    value: this.state.field,
};
this.socket.emit('message', message);
```

I listen for messages like this:
`this.socket.on('message', this.handleMessage)` where handleMessage simply sets the state with the new message.

Can anyone see why not?

UPDATE: Here is more of the code to see: https://jsbin.com/pakeyavefo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong.  First, you can open the Chrome debugger on the desired recipient page, go to the network tab, find the webSocket connection that is the transport for the socket.io connection and then see if the recipient is actually getting the traffic (you will have to look inside the webSocket packets).  Then, you can would fire up the nodejs debugger and step through the call to `socket.to(data.roomId).emit(data)` and see what it finds in that room and what it attempts to send to.  You need to know whether the sending is the problem or the receiving is the problem.

Comment: I feel it could be the receiving. I did a console.log in those server callbacks i have and i get roomIds and data.
Am i correct in thinking this is where we wait for a message `this.socket.on('message', this.handleMessage)`?
I updated my question with more of the code.

Comment: You should see something in `console.log('ms', message);` inside of `handleMessage()` if you are receiving that message.

Comment: hmm nope i dont see anything there.

Comment: See what I modified my  answer to below.   `socket.to(data.roomId).emit(data);` doesn't have a message name.

Comment: Found the issue! `socket.in(data.roomId).emit(data);` should be `socket.in(data.roomId).emit('message', data);`. i.e. i found to add the "what" I am emitting

Comment: ah yes same time solved. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
socket.to(data.roomId).emit(data);
```

You need to send both a message name and some data.  You aren't sending a message name, therefore that event (if it even gets sent) won't match any listeners on the client.  Perhaps this is supposed to be:

```
socket.to(data.roomId).emit('message', data);
```

Comment: `this.socket.emit('room', this.state.roomId);` from what i know this emit is caught on the server to join that roomId. Then there is a separate "message" emit that actually sends the message. And that data payload contains the roomId for the server to know where to emit it to.

Comment: @strangeQuirks - Yeah, I got confused with your code.  What about my second point about `this.handleMessage.bind(this)`?

Comment: That is not necessary has handleMessage looks like this: `handleMessage = (message) => {}`

Comment: The goal I am trying to achieve/learn, is a user enters a roomId, a socket connection is made to that room, and if someone else joins that room they can basically chat together.